# 3d sprites using bitmap/drawable?

Tags: android, sprite

I understand the concept of drawing sprites (2D). Basically you load in the images/drawables and put them into bitmap, renders them by drawing on canvas or as simple as loading imageview with a src file.

I know this may not be that accurate but I hope I am getting the point across.

My question is, if I want these sprites to be 3d. Is it along the same lines but just fancier images? Or am I missing the point completely?

Execuse my limited knowledge. Been reading a lot and experimenting but definitly still "noob".

Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you, but when you use android to draw 3d object. Do you just load the object up like you load images or totally different? I.e. how easy is it to change a game that have 2D image and make it 3D? Does the whole foundation need to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`am I missing the point completely?` **Definetely**.

3D **objects** are completely different beasts from 2D painted **images**.
A 3D object can be rotated in space and it's defined by 3D vectors.

To deepen your knowledge about the 3D universe, have a peek into a 3D software, such as `Blender` (which is free on Windows, Mac and Linux).

---

`totally different?` **YES**.

`how easy is it to change a game that have 2D image and make it 3D?` If you want **real 3D** (i.e. rotating objects in real time), you have **a lot of work** to do.
If you are happy with just making the existing sprites `look a bit like 3D` (**fake** 3D), then it's only a **sprite redrawing** (download Blender, learn how to use it, draw your 3D objects and render them in 2D).

You can also try creating the so called `2.5D parallax effect`, but it would take you longer.

`Does the whole foundation need to be changed` **YES**, if you want real 3D. Google for `android 3d engine free`.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right path. I liked your Blender and 2.5D effect

Comment: Some games use the parallax effect to simulate 3D. More about stereoscopy: look for `wigglegrams` (not much usable in a game, in my opinion, but a must see!)